# Decreasing maximum health in Minecraft 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I decrease the maximum health of a player using commands in Minecraft 1.8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible using item attributes with a command like this:

```
replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.feet chainmail_boots 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:-10,Operation:0,UUIDMost:12272,UUIDLeast:110438}]}
```

What the above command does is replace one of a selected entity's armor slots (in this case their feet) with a piece of armor that has a negative `maxHealth` attribute, causing their maximum health to lower.

You can change the number after `Amount:` to change how much their health drops by; 1 unit is half a heart.

Note that their health will go back up if they take the armor piece off, so you will probably want to have the command on a clock.

Answer (score -1):

and for a button and only 1 heart, use this:
replaceitem entity @p slot.armor.head stone_button 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:-18,Operation:0,UUIDMost:12272,UUIDLeast:110438}]}

Comment: This adds nothing new and is essentially just a copy/paste of the accepted answer.